# InDesign script searching for a word and printing page number(s)

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I need an InDesign script that does the following:

- Searching for a specific word in a specific paragraph style throughout the document
- Printing the page number(s) to the console or as a .txt (I mean not the amount of pages, but the page number(s), i.e. p6, p11, p48 etc)

I am using CS6 and JS.

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
app.findGrepPreferences=NothingEnum.NOTHING; //to reset the Grep search
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = 'Your text will be here'; //the word(s) you are searching
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.itemByName ("The name of your paragraph Style") //make sure it is spelled exactly as it is in the paragraph styles panel, including case
var fnd = app.activeDocument.findGrep (); //execute search
for (var i = 0; i < fnd.length; i++) { //loop through results and store the results
    $.write (fnd [i].parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name + '\n'); //output to console in Extendscript
}
```

One thing to know is that text frames outside the pages (on pasteboard) will cause this script to error so you need to try/catch it. But this is the general idea. Also this works in CC but in CS there was no 'parentPage' so this might need to be worked around.